# C++ Qt5 Net-snmp LNK Error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, snmp, net-snmp

I have downloaded net-snmp from
  http://softlayer-ams.dl.sourceforge.net/project/net-snmp/net-snmp%20binaries/5.7-binaries/net-snmp-5.7.0-1.x86.exe

and installed.

Now, I am trying to follow this tutorial to get stated (http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Simple_Application)

I am trying to use net-snmp in my C++ Qt5 applicaton with VC++ 2010 Compiler but I get the following error

```
snmptest.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__generate_Ku referenced in    function "public: void __thiscall SnmpTest::doSnmp(void)" (?doSnmp@SnmpTest@@QAEXXZ)

snmptest.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__snmp_sess_init referenced in function "public: void __thiscall SnmpTest::doSnmp(void)" (?doSnmp@SnmpTest@@QAEXXZ)

snmptest.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__init_snmp referenced in function "public: void __thiscall SnmpTest::doSnmp(void)" (?doSnmp@SnmpTest@@QAEXXZ)

C:\build\debug\a.exe:-1: Fehler: LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

snmptest.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol
```

I added this line to my *.pro file:

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:\snmp_5.7.0\include"
```

SnmpTest.h

```
#ifndef SNMPTEST_H
#define SNMPTEST_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <net-snmp/library/transform_oids.h>

class SnmpTest
{
public:
    SnmpTest();
    void doSnmp();
};

#endif // SNMPTEST_H
```

SnmpTest.cpp

```
SnmpTest::SnmpTest()
{
}

void SnmpTest::doSnmp()
{
    const char *our_v3_passphrase = "XXXXX";
    struct snmp_session session, *ss;
    struct snmp_pdu *pdu;
    struct snmp_pdu *response;

    oid anOID[MAX_OID_LEN];
    size_t anOID_len = MAX_OID_LEN;

    struct variable_list *vars;
    int status;

    /*
    * Initialize the SNMP library
    */
    init_snmp("snmpapp");

    snmp_sess_init(&session);
    session.peername = "xxxxx";
    session.version=SNMP_VERSION_3;

    /* set the SNMPv3 user name */
    session.securityName = _strdup("YYYY");
    session.securityNameLen = strlen(session.securityName);

    /* set the security level to authenticated, but not encrypted */
    session.securityLevel = SNMP_SEC_LEVEL_AUTHNOPRIV;

    /* set the authentication method to MD5 */
    session.securityAuthProto = usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol;
    session.securityAuthProtoLen = sizeof(usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol)/sizeof(oid);
    session.securityAuthKeyLen = USM_AUTH_KU_LEN;

    /* set the authentication key to a MD5 hashed version of our
      passphrase (which must be at least 8
      characters long) */
    if(generate_Ku(
            session.securityAuthProto,
            session.securityAuthProtoLen,
            (u_char *) our_v3_passphrase, strlen(our_v3_passphrase),
            session.securityAuthKey,
            &session.securityAuthKeyLen) != SNMPERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error generating Ku from authentication pass phrase.";
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the include path is not enough. You need to link against the library, naturally, otherwise all the symbols will be unresolved for the linker. Try

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\snmp_5.7.0\include"
    LIBS+= -L"C:\snmp_5.7.0\lib" -lnetsnmp
}
```

or something similar. You can even specify the absolute path to the library should it be located elsewhere than beside the application. Check how exactly the library is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are 4 files called netsnmp.lib, netsnmpagent.lib, netsnmpmibs.lib and netsnmptrapd.lib in the directory C:\snmp_5.7.0\lib. Do I need to keek the "l" before the name? I rebiuld the project but the error remains :(

Comment: @user2357505: hmm, those seems to be static libraries, but that ought to work, too. I suggest to check which libraries provide these symbols. You can specify all of them with separate `-lfoo -lbar -lbaz`, etc, arrangement if you need all of them, but I think you missed to specify the path with `-L` in your previous trial.

Comment: Okay, now it is building but it instantly crashes. Any idea on that?

Comment: @user2357505: that seems to be a different issue than what the question is asking, so glad to see that you resolved the building issue. As for the crash, I think you will need to check the backtrace to see where it crashes.

Comment: Thank you ver very much for your help! I cant even start the debugger. So I think it might be related to that problem?

Comment: @user2357505: check [this link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-engines.html#installing-native-debuggers) out about how to set the debugger up on Windows.

Comment: I have already used a debugger. The problem is whenever I call init_snmp("snmpapp") it will build but instant crash without a chance to get debugging informations.

Comment: @user2357505: does the example program work for you in the link?

Comment: No, I have deleted anything below init_snmp("snmpapp"); in the void SnmpTest::doSnmp() method. If I also delete the line init_snmp("snmpapp") it will run the debugger as expected.

Comment: @user2357505: are you sure that you are not mixing up different types of builds, i.e. release/debug?

Comment: Yes, I just made debug builds. I cleard the project , run qmake and then run. Results in a crash with init_snmp("snmpapp"); and is working good without this line :(

Comment: @user2357505: you do not mix arch types either, like 32 vs. 64, yeah? Also, have you made sure that the library was built with the same compiler?

Comment: I hope I do not. I am running on Windows 7 64 bit using a Visual C++ 2010 32 bit compiler with Qt5.02. I downloaded the net-snmp binaries from http://softlayer-ams.dl.sourceforge.net/project/net-snmp/net-snmp%20binaries/5.7-binaries/net-snmp-5.7.0-1.x86.exe

Comment: Is the libary not working for me? If this is the case what can I do to make this *.lib file work? It would be realy great if you could advice